# Google Developer Console optimization tips(minSdkVersion) for tablet design

Tags: android

Find below what google has to say for making an application tablet optimized in its latest Google IO-13 initiatives. My question is :-  Why do my app has to have min sdk version greater than 11 to make it tablet optimized? This means my application is not for tablets if I am supporting gingerbread phones which is still active in lot of devices.

> At a minimum, check the  element to make sure that:
>
> ```
> targetSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or higher (14 or higher is recommended), OR
> minSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or higher.
> If a maxSdkVersion attribute is declared, it must have a value of 11 or higher. Note that, in general, the use of maxSdkVersion is not recommended.
> ```

Comment: The only people who could answer this question work for Google, and they are highly unlikely to respond here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`<uses-sdk>` documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html):

> [...] setting [the targetSdkVersion] value to "11" or higher allows the
>   system to apply a new default theme (Holo) to your app when running on
>   Android 3.0 or higher and **also disables screen compatibility mode when
>   running on larger screens** (because support for API level 11 implicitly
>   supports larger screens).

There are a few key things to note here.

- You don't need to set minSdkVersion to 11. They suggest setting *either* minSdkVersion OR targetSdkVersion to 11. Doing either will have the same effect for tablets.
- You can have an application that runs on tablets just fine without doing this. It simply will use screen compatibility mode, which is not optimal.
- If you aren't targeting a higher API version (or implicitly doing so with minSdkVersion), then your app will also not use Holo (without a library), which is a standard UI expectation for apps on newer (3.0+) devices.

Comment: Thanks..But the document does not say or, it says "At a minimum, check the element to make sure that:"